# I'm struck with this error (MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'name' in 'field list')

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

I have the following table "test_tbl1" in MySQL. It has the columns "id, name, sal". I'm using the following code in eclipse and trying to insert the data from Excel. I'm getting the following error for each row which i'm fetching from excel.

```
FAILED: testDataProviderExample("101", "sam", "10000")
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'name' in 'field list'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
```

---

```
public class dbcon extends SeleneseTestBase{
Connection conn = null;
Statement stmt = null;
@BeforeTest
public static void connection()
{

        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            System.out.println("hi");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            e1.printStackTrace();

        }

}

@BeforeTest     

public void MysqlConnection()  //we need to add the Dataprovider name[name="DP"] to pass the data from excel sheet

{   

    try {

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root", "admin");

        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

        System.out.println("hi1");

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

        return;

    }
                System.out.println("Testing Testfile1");

}



@DataProvider(name = "DP1")

public Object[][] createData1() throws Exception{

    Object[][] retObjArr=getTableArray("C:\\my folder\\Kenscio\\New folder\\data4.xls","DataPool", "mysqldata");

    return(retObjArr);

}



@Test (dataProvider = "DP1")

public void testDataProviderExample(String empid, String name, String sal) throws Exception {   

    System.out.println("id: " + empid);

    System.out.println("name: " + name);

    System.out.println("sal: " + sal);
    System.out.println("hi2");
    String sql = "insert into test_tbl(id,name,sal)" + "values(?,?,?)";
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root", "admin");
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    preparedStatement.setString(1, "id");
    preparedStatement.setString(2, "name");
    preparedStatement.setString(3, "sal");
    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
    }
```

Comment: Your description talks about a table named "test_tbl1". But your code inserts into a table named "test_tbl". Check your table.

Comment: thanks. I got my output.

Answer (score 1):

You said that you have a table name  `test_tbl1`, but your query said

```
String sql = "insert into test_tbl(id,name,sal)" + "values(?,?,?)";
```

i think that you have to modify the sql to be like:

```
String sql = "insert into test_tbl1 (id,name,sal)" + "values(?,?,?)";
```

Answer (score 1):

The error says that there is no column called `name` in the table that you are inserting into. This may be because you have a table called `test_tbl1`, but your code refers to `test_tbl`. This presumes `test_tbl` exists and does not have that column. Try running the SQL by hand using the mysql client.

Also, your table name is poor, I'm presuming it's an employee table, if so call it employee, and you will avoid similar mistakes.

The following concatenation is unnecessary:

`String sql = "insert into test_tbl(id,name,sal)" + "values(?,?,?)";`